# Guardar fecha al cerrar aplicación

Tags: android

Me puede alguien decir como puedo meter el SharedPreferences,supongo que es la solucion a mi problema, para que al cerrar la aplicacion me guarde los datos y al abrirla de nuevo continuen ahi, hasta que los vuelva a cambiar?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView et1, et2, et3, et4;

    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_descarga);
        et2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_proxdescarga);
        et3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_falta);
        et4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_actual);

        et1.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
        et3.setText("");
        et4.setText("");


    }

    public void inttroduce_fecha(View v) {

        final Calendar dateIni = Calendar.getInstance();

        mYear = dateIni.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = dateIni.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = dateIni.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth));
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        String dateString = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        et1.setText("Descargada el " + dateString);

                        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth+28));
                        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        String dateString1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());

                        et2.setText("Descargar el " + dateString1);


                        Date d=new Date();

                        SimpleDateFormat fecc=new SimpleDateFormat("d, MMMM, yyyy");
                        String fechacComplString = fecc.format(d);
                        et4.setText("Hoy es " + fechacComplString);

                        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

                        cal1.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        cal2.set(year, monthOfYear, (dayOfMonth+28));

                        long milis1 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
                        long milis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();

                        long diff = milis2 - milis1;

                        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                        et3.setText("Faltan : " + diffDays + " dias " );

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Te refieres a la fecha? y donde la desplegarìas al iniciar si fue guardada anteriormente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Puedes usar **[getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences())**

Te sugiero estos métodos para guardar y obtener el valor guardado:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String prefKey, int value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt(prefKey, value);
    editor.commit();
}



public int getValuePreference(Context context, String prefKey) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getInt(prefKey, 0);
}
```

de esta forma cuando cierres tu `Activity` guardas los valores:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Year", mYear);
    saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Month", mMonth);
    saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Day", mDay);
}
```

y al iniciar tu `Activity` los recuperas:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
        mYear = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Year");
        mMonth = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Month");
        mDay = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "Day");
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Si Jorgesys, asi es, pero me refiero si cierro la aplicacion, ¿Hay alguna manera, o recurro a base de datos?

Comment: Puedes usar SharedPreferences o una base de datos si la cantidad de datos es considerable.